# Material ui AppBar text color change to white / back functionality

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How does material ui AppBar change text color to white / black color depending on if AppBar color is dark or light
is there a function that i can use from material ui? i checked their document and couldn't find function myself
i have tried css

```
<style>
.container {
  background-color: #ff0001;
  padding: 15px;
}

.container p {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white
}
</style>



<div class="container">
  <p> asd </p>
</div>
```

But it doesnt give only white / black color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Material UI has built-in support for easily switching between light and dark modes. All you need to do is build theme objects for both modes, wrap your code with a `ThemeProvider`, and use state (and context) to toggle between light and dark mode. Reference links:</s>

1. [ThemeProvider](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/)
2. [Theme object](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/). Here, you can set the `palette.type` property as `light` or `dark` as per your convenience.

Correction:

Material-UI uses the `main` color in `palette.primary/secondary` as an input to get the ideal contrasting text color. This works for all MUI components (like AppBar). The exact source code is available [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js), in the `getContrastText` function. They have also linked sources in the code that use scss to achieve the same.

I didn't fully understand the logic behind this implementation, but I hope the linked code answers your question.

Edit 2:

The `getContrastText` can be used with the `theme` object in the following manner:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  "key": {
    "color": theme.palette.getContrastText("#cfe8fc") // returns rgba(0,0,0,0.87)
  }
})
```

This `theme` object can also be obtained using the `useTheme` hook or the `withStyles` HOC.

Comment: this isnt what i am asking, try running the code i provided to better understand the question please,.

Comment: What i am trying to say is, if you set your primary color to a dark color material ui app bar text will automatically change to white, and vise virsa, i tried to achieve this functionality by css but its close but not exactly like MUI

Comment: @ZOthix, I see what you mean now. I've edited my answer to be more appropriate.

Comment: Kindly add example code to get contrast color

`theme.palette.getContrastText("YourColorHere") `

so its easier for others to get this answer as well